# storing modbus register address and corresponding set values to mysql database

Tags: python, pymodbus

I am trying to run a Modbus server code which just stores the Modbus register address and corresponding values to MySQL database. for example, I want to send a command to the Modbus server to set 40001  address value to 25. Modbus server just saves this address and values to the database. Anyone have idea on it?
I am using pymodbus python library.

Comment: Have a look in to the examples, there is an example to save the values using `SqlSlaveContext` [here](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/2ef91e9e565b10fc9abc0840c87cf4a29f3d9bbf/examples/common/dbstore_update_server.py)

Comment: Hi Sanju, in the example randomly stores address and values to the database. I am trying to store the address and values that I am sending from the client. Do you have any Idea. Could you please share with me?

Comment: Basically, you will have to come up with your custom datablock and handle the write events. You can refer to https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/dev/examples/common/custom_datablock.py example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Below is my code and I get illegal data address when I send command from client software.I am sending command to 40001 to set the value 50.

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSparseDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import SqlSlaveContext
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer, ModbusAsciiFramer

import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
class CustomDataBlock(ModbusSparseDataBlock):
    def setValues(self, address, value):
        super(ModbusSparseDataBlock, self).setValues(address, value)
        print("wrote {} to {}".format(value, address))


def run_custom_db_server():
    block  = CustomDataBlock([0]*100)
    store  = SqlSlaveContext(di=block, co=block, hr=block, ir=block)
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
    identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
    identity.VendorName = 'pymodbus'
    identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
    identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
    identity.ProductName = 'pymodbus Server'
    identity.ModelName = 'pymodbus Server'
    identity.MajorMinorRevision = '2.2.0'
    StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("localhos", 502))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_custom_db_server()
`
from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSparseDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import SqlSlaveContext
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer, ModbusAsciiFramer

import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
class CustomDataBlock(ModbusSparseDataBlock):
    def setValues(self, address, value):
        super(ModbusSparseDataBlock, self).setValues(address, value)
        print("wrote {} to {}".format(value, address))


def run_custom_db_server():
    block  = CustomDataBlock([0]*100)
    store  = SqlSlaveContext(di=block, co=block, hr=block, ir=block)
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
    identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
    identity.VendorName = 'pymodbus'
    identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
    identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
    identity.ProductName = 'pymodbus Server'
    identity.ModelName = 'pymodbus Server'
    identity.MajorMinorRevision = '2.2.0'
    StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("localhos", 502))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_custom_db_server()
```